# Load UICollectionView cells without reuse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView that will only display three cells. Each cell is of the same type of custom collectionViewCell that I've set up in storyboard. I only want each cell instantiated once and only once; not reused.

How can I return cells from cellForItemAtIndexPath: datasource method that aren't reused? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can simply use a unique `reuseIdentifier` for each one, but why bother. Just let the collection view handle it

Comment: Paulw11's answer works, I'm also curious as to why you would want to do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reusing a `UICollectionViewCell` doesn't mean you're getting rid of the previous ones that are no longer on the screen.

#### It's a structured process for memory efficiency and here's how it works:

1. There are a distinct number of cells automatically generated by the `UICollectionView` based on the `UICollectionViewLayout` you're needing.
2. These cells are built upon a `UIScrollView` that ***reuses*** them instead of allocating memory for every cell that will eventually be appearing.
3. imagine the dataset being a "wheel" and it's size dependent on how many cells you're needing to create.
4. Let's say your "wheel" has a total of 100 different "views" that will populate the cells
5. If the screen can only show 5 at a time, it wouldn't make sense to load all 100... Just the **5** that will be within the view and the ones preparing to enter the screen as you're scrolling..
6. By Using the `UICollectionViewDataSource` Protocols, your collection view repopulates the cell that just left the screen and puts it below, or above, the displayed list to be "reused" instead of causing memory problems.

Collection Views are incredibly efficient and I would recommend utilizing their built in Memory saving `dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier`.

### Now, to answer your question:

You would get the result you're wanting by putting the Necessary Data you'll need within the cells (possibly making a subclass of the `UICollectionViewCell` if needed) inside a `NSArray`.

You'll access each object (1 - 100 in our example) using the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and as your scroll, the basic principle of reusing the cells will display the NSArray objects that are needed to be displayed.

I'm hoping this makes sense and it helps you solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. The root cause of my issue is I am not fundamentally relying on a data object to provide as a consistent data source for my collection view. Refactoring now.

Comment: @vikzilla No problem. Also, if the data object is changing at all, make sure you're using the `reloadData` method properly and updating the the UICollectionView Protocol methods with the correct values

Answer (score -2):

Use properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionViewCell *firstCell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionViewCell *secondCell;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionViewCell *thirdCell;
```

In viewDidLoad you can create it:

```
 self.firstCell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];
// Do you need...
```

And your delegate methods, look like:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        return self.firstCell;
        break;
    case 1:
        return self.secondCell;
        break;
    case 2:
        return self.thirdCell;
        break;

    default:
        return nil;
        break;
}

}
```

Comment: Why someone give down vote, I do not understand. Onik IV is correct since it is answering what is asking. It is not wrong. Not the best way but sometimes you just need limited number of cells like 3 or 5. And when you don't what to deal with page view controller, it may be useful just 3 cells on screen.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I  harly ever use Storyboard, but when it was launch, I liked the static tableViewController. I usually do all views by code, and this is the way to do static table view (or collection view) by code. In my opinion good solution to forms, or when you have very litle number of cells and they are differnt.