# UICollectionView: control when cells are ready to be reused

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

As far as I can tell, the only real fundamental reason I want to use collectionviews is to have the efficient built-in cell re-use system (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32574877/7612797). For example, if I want to display 100 elements, but only 5 of them show up at a time as being visible, I should use a collectionView.

However, the collectionView's recycling model is completely based on the visible bounds of the collectionView. In other words, cells get disappeared almost the instant they leave the collectionView.

I find this criteria rather stringent and inflexible for my needs. Is there a way I can override the determination of when a cell is no longer in use and should be dequeued?

My only other resort is to write my own collectionview with more flexibility on reuse determination.

Comment: I don't believe what you're describing is possible with UICollectionView.  What are your needs, that require you to have cells that aren't visible but also aren't allowed to get recycled?  In all likelihood, rearchitecting your code to remove that requirement will be a lot easier than re-creating UICollectionView.

Comment: Your basic assumption is flawed. The cells are a merely a vehicle for displaying information from some other source - your data model. There is no need for them to live beyond the time they are displayed.

Comment: @JamieA, I have a horizontal collection of *variably* sized cells, that may be sectioned.

When the user touches the leftmost-visible cell they see, I want the collection to scroll so that the contentOffset is equal to the left side of the cell that is left of the cell the user touched.

In other words, if the user touched <2> when the visible cells were:
<2> <3> <4>

The collectionview should display:
<1> <2> <3>

Its annoying to calculate the indexPath of the cell that is "left" of a particular cell without the actual frames of cells outside the visible bounds to work with.

Comment: @WinstonDu thanks for that clarification.  You should be able to do the following: 1. Since you have the UICollectionViewCell that was tapped, use `indexPath(for: UICollectionViewCell)` to convert that cell to an IndexPath. 2. Calculating the IndexPath of the cell to the left should be straightforward. 3. Use `scrollToItem(at: IndexPath, at: ScrollPosition, animated: Bool)` to scroll to that indexPath. It's not trivial, but it'll be way less painful than re-creating UICollectionView yourself.

Comment: "Calculating the IndexPath of the cell to the left should be straightforward." Unfortunately, for more complicated collectionViewlayouts, it ain't. For example, imagine that I had a grid of cells (where number of items in each column could vary based on item size). It is impossible to determine the index path of a cell that I know will be one column to the left of cell I tapped. This is why fundamentally, the UICollectionView design is inflexible.